# Why buttons doesn't fit to translation?

Tags: qt, button

I've a size problem with translated text. If I use a translation the text not fits with the size.

[image: Example]

Original text:

[Save icon] Save

Translated text (german):

[Save icon] Speichern

Is there any option to resize the buttons for a translation?

Comment: did you use layout? you should add your code or project.

Comment: Yes, I use a layout. The mainwindow has a vertical layout and the button is in a horizontal layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `adjustSize();` *after* the ui setup.

Answer (score -1):

QPushButton tries to size to its text by default, but your window is probably not wide enough. Consider reduzing fontSize or increase your application window's width.